# Shared Memory and Windows Server Containers

Tags: c#, .net, windows, server, containers

Does anyone know if one can share a memory segment using .NETs MemoryMappedFile API across Windows Server Containers.

Comment: It looks like this is supported in Linux. https://dzone.com/articles/docker-in-action-the-shared-memory-namespace